# How to install mongodb php driver on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: php, mongodb, macos

I tried installing with homebrew but it seems those files were removed and I used

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

I get this error

```
-I/private/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/MongoDB/Monitoring/ -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/contrib/ -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/ -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libbson/src/ -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libbson/src/jsonsl/ -I/
private/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libbson/src/bson/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-crypto-openssl.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/.libs/mongoc-crypto-openssl.o
/private/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-crypto-openssl.c:24:10: fatal error: 'openssl/sha.h' file not found
#include <openssl/sha.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-crypto-openssl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: i am stucked in same issue nssl.c:24:10: fatal error: 'openssl/sha.h' file not found #include <openssl/sha.h> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. make: *** [src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-crypto-openssl.lo] Error 1 ERROR: `make' failed  have you found the solutions ?

Comment: may be this could help i was having same problem https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/768715/i-am-getting-error-fatal-error-openssl-sha-h-file-not-found-while-installin/768769#768769

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this on their bug tracking page https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/523